# Regex to match first and third groups of numbers between special characters

Tags: python, regex

I am currently working on a large data processing script in Python that uses subprocesses to extract strings of text from files. The strings that I am receiving are in the format of:

`-R##/##/##/##`

An example of this would be `-R-120/-115/-30/-20` (the four numbers can be either positive or negative)

I am trying to come up with a regex expression to match the first and third numbers, so for the example above I would need `-120` and `-30`.

Could anyone steer me in the right direction for a clean way to go about doing this?

Comment: `r'-R([+-\d]+)/[+-\d]+/([+-\d]+)/[+-\d]+'` The parentheses are a 'capturing group'

Comment: Do positive numbers have a `+` in front or just a lack of `-`?

Comment: @moogle Positive numbers have nothing in front of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in python with 2 capturing groups to grab your numbers:

```
>>> s = '-R-120/-115/-30/-20'
>>> print re.findall(r'^\D*?([-+]?\d+)\D*?[-+]?\d+\D*?([-+]?\d+)', s)

[('-120', '-30')]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1lf00m/3)